# html :hover on div border style

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a div with round corners. When the mouse is above the div, the corners need to be right. How can I do that?

This is what I wrote so far:

```
<style>
    #ex1
    {
        border: 2px outset black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

</style>

<style>
    #ex1:hover
    {
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In your ":hover" style block, just reset the border-radius to 0px.  Also, you probably don't really need to repeat some of the style elements under "hover" that are the same as non-hover (eg. text-align).  Whatever your "hover" style block doesn't set - that's already been set in the default style block for the element - will still stick

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the same style again for hover also. you just need to put the changes what you want to see in the hover styles.

```
#ex1:hover
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Craig posted:

```
<style>
    #ex1 {
        border: 2px outset black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    #ex1:hover {
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
</style>
```